# Android Studio 4 cannot detect java code and Cannot open SDK Manager,Settings

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk, android-studio-4.0

I just `updated` to latest android studio and had `invalidated caches and restart` but after that my project files are all red and android studio cannot detect java.
Whenever I hover on red line, It shows a `configure JDK` option. 
I had downloaded latest jdk from oracle website and selected that in java path but that also didn't work. I am not able to open settings, SDK manager, neither can I configure SDK.

> Below is the error dialog

[image: Error dialog]

> I tried all the options below but cannot solve the issue

[image: JDK selection dialog]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after hours of debugging , here is how I solved all the issues.

> **Cause of the problem** : Improper Update

1. Checked **IDE log**, which was showing an exception thrown by a plugin. So I uninstalled that plugin.
2. **Deleted old folder** of android studio `.Android-studio-3.6` present inside `C\Users\<Username>\`
3. Most of the errors were gone but android studio was shwowing a warning **"*Two different JDK locations are selected for building gradle....*"**, so I went to control panel and **deleted all old versions of java** except for the **latest JDK `14.0.1`** which I downloaded from [Oracle website](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk14-downloads.html).
4. Still it was showing the same error so I **downloaded Android Studio 4.0 exe** file from [their website](https://developer.android.com/studio/?gclid=CjwKCAjwiMj2BRBFEiwAYfTbChnTFy9X66vHhkA2EBw2pyYl3M0r-AxyTqxs-ghEuxk5RbDP7WXbQRoCJg8QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) and **re-installed** Android studio. While Reinstalling, I **did not select Android Virtual device** as it was already installed.

Comment: Regarding your second point, a dialog box will show you asking whether or not you want to delete the folder of older studio. I always delete and I haven't faced problems like this. Just today, I updated to version 4 without any problem.

Comment: I had selected delete option only, but it was not deleted ....

Comment: Oh! and it is better to use android studio's own jdk which is originally an `openjdk` than the one from `oracle` website. They changes the licensing conditions. Now, we need to pay for its commercial use I guess.

Answer (score 6):

In my case is the `CSV Plugin`'s fault.
After I noticed en error in the right of the status bar said that CSV plugin startup failed, then I disabled this plugin in the Report Issue dialog
Then restart Android Studio will fix the cannot open settings problem

[plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phRja.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not setup JDK.Try to setup JDK and i think it will help you to solve the problem.

Comment: I've installed the downloaded .exe file and set the PATH variable to the bin folder of installed JDK. What else should I do ?

Comment: As per your image there is option "Setup JDK".Click that and tell me what it show.